# Random ID values from the array

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

How do I randomly select an ID in a JSON array of this type?

```
{
    "398134753850556416": {"id": "398134753850556416"},
    "398134757854556416": {"id": "398134757854556416"}
}
```

I Tried to implement it like this:

```js
const id1 = require("./json/id.json");

const values = Object.values(id1[member.id]) 
const math = values[parseInt(Math.random() * values.length)]
console.log(math)
```

Error:
For some reason, it looks for 2 values instead of 1.
If the first one is deleted, it gives an error, as if there is nothing further.

Comment: Please include the exact error message. You can add `>` to the start of the line to give the error message "quote" formatting.

Comment: Is it a nesting problem? Also, How do you know it's looking for exactly `2` values? I'm also not clear where `member` (`member.id`) is defined.

Comment: Can you please show relevant code from `./json/id.json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I randomly select an ID in a JSON <s>array</s> of this type?
>       {
>           "398134753850556416": {"id": "398134753850556416"},
>           "398134757854556416": {"id": "398134757854556416"}
>       }

I believe that’s an **object**, not an array.

I’m assuming that code block that you posted is what’s in your `./json/id.json` file, and that `member.id` is a valid key like `"398134753850556416"`. Let’s look through your code:

```
const id1 = require("./json/id.json");
```

`id1` would be the object `{ "398134753850556416": {"id": "398134753850556416"}, "398134757854556416": {"id": "398134757854556416"} }`.

```
const values = Object.values(id1[member.id])
```

`id["398134753850556416"]` would be the object `{"id": "398134753850556416"}`. Passing that object as an argument for `Object.values()`, the `values` constant would be the array `["398134753850556416"]`.

```
const math = values[parseInt(Math.random() * values.length)]
```

`values.length` would be `1`. `Math.random() * 1` would not change the original randomised floating-point value. Passing that value that’s between 0-1 (including 0 but not 1) as an argument for `parseInt()` would always return `0`. `values[0]`, and thus the `math` constant, would be the string `"398134753850556416"`.

```
console.log(math)
```

You’re essentially **always logging the value of `member.id`**!

> For some reason, it looks for <s>2</s> value<s>s</s> instead of <s>1</s>.

I assume you mean it’s always logging **1** value instead of randomly choosing between the **2** values in your JSON file. Well, that behaviour does match what your current code should actually end up doing.

> If the first one is deleted, it gives an error, as if there is nothing further.

Reading this, I think `member.id` is indeed `"398134753850556416”`, and so, deleting line 2 of your JSON file (the first key-value pair) which uses that string as its key would cause an issue, since you do essentially call `id1["398134753850556416"]` in your code.

Alright. So, how do you get the behaviour that you wish? I’m going to assume that the `.id` of each *object* value of your main JSON object’s properties is identical to that *object*’s key, as is the case in the code block you gave. Ie, `{ “same”: {“id”: “same”}, ... }`.

```
let objectFromJsonFile = require("./json/id.json"); // This would be { "398134753850556416": {"id": "398134753850556416"}, "398134757854556416": {"id": "398134757854556416"} }
let arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(objectFromJsonFile); // This would be ["398134753850556416", "398134757854556416"]
let randomKey = arrayOfKeys[
    Math.floor(
        Math.random() * arrayOfKeys.length
    )
]; // Aka random ID
```

I hope that answers your question! I’m still learning myself, so others, feel free to correct me where I am wrong.